# Golang handlefunc with channel

Tags: go

I think this question has been asked before (and probably more than once) but I can't find it...

Im learning Go, and I wanted to extend the classical web server example by sending a channel to the "handler".

I have this standard thing:

```
func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   io.WriteString(w, "Hello world!")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

And now I would like the "hello" function to be able to write stuff on a channel, for someone to consume... The way I have done with "normal" functions is to create a channel:

```
c := make(chan string)
```

and pass c in the call to the function. Something like:

```
dosomething(c)
```

But... how would I go about doing that if I want "hello" to get access to the channel c?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two other ways to do this (other than exporting your channels as in the previous answer).

The first is to use a function to return another handler function.  When the function is returned, it will create a closure around the channel.

```
func makeHello(logger chan string) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        logger <- r.Host
        io.WriteString(w, "Hello world!")
    }
}
```

The second is to use a struct which holds the channel as a member and use pointer receiver methods to handle the request...

```
type DataPasser struct {
    logs chan string
}

func (p *DataPasser) handleHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    p.logs <- r.URL.String()
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello world")
}
```

This is a full working example (just hit /1 and /2 to see the two examples)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    // METHOD 1
    logs := make(chan string)
    go logLogs(logs)
    handleHello := makeHello(logs)

    // METHOD 2
    passer := &DataPasser{logs: make(chan string)}
    go passer.log()

    http.HandleFunc("/1", handleHello)
    http.HandleFunc("/2", passer.handleHello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9999", nil)
}

// METHOD 1

func makeHello(logger chan string) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        logger <- r.Host
        io.WriteString(w, "Hello world!")
    }
}

func logLogs(logger chan string) {
    for item := range logger {
        fmt.Println("1. Item", item)
    }
}

// METHOD 2

type DataPasser struct {
    logs chan string
}

func (p *DataPasser) handleHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    p.logs <- r.URL.String()
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello world")
}

func (p *DataPasser) log() {
    for item := range p.logs {
        fmt.Println("2. Item", item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the great example. I ended up using method 1, and it does the job perfectly.

Comment: Coming from python I could not figure out how to do such a simple thing. Funny how there actually is a very simple solution to the problem, all that was needed is a paradigm shift.

Comment: method 2 won't work. Every time a channel is added to main(), the server spin up but doesn't work.
Either by using a struct ad receiver or by global var chan.

Comment: @Andy Does the example code above not work?  I think it shows pretty clearly that method 2 does work but I'd be interested to know if I am wrong.

Comment: I also end up using first method, it was useful

Answer (score 2):

There a few ways to solve this problem, the simplest is to define an exported channel in a package and import said package where ever you want to use the channel.

```
package mychannel

var Chan = make(chan string)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! In the end I used the method proposed by sberry instead, but I still appreciate the help!

Comment: This is like "Go-style Singleton Pattern".

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- nah, just a global variable. You could have a singleton in Go with a private type with a public constructor function that returned the private var that was the instance of the private type, this would enforce the singleton pattern. I'm not sure I've seen anyone who codes in Go do much of that though.