# Passing the channel into a handle function with Context.WithValue

Tags: function, go, concurrency, handle, channel

I would like to use a channel for managing the global shared variables (something like: map[string]MyStruct) into my serverApp (as I know it's more "go way" rather than use sync.Mutex). I found this question ([Golang handlefunc with channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419876/golang-handlefunc-with-channel/71292829#71292829)) with two possible solutions. But I know it's possible to pass the channel with context.WithValue in the middleware (for necessary routes) and get access to it from the handle function if I need it? Or are there any reasons why I shouldn't do it and better use the "extend method" (from the @sberry answer) instead?

I use Echo Framework in this example:

```
func bindChannel(CmdChan chan CmdOp) echo.MiddlewareFunc {
    return func(next echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {
        return func(c echo.Context) error {
            c.Set("cmdChan", CmdChan)
            return next(c)
        }
    }
}

var CmdChan chan CmdOp
   type CmdOp struct {
    Type            string
    Key             string
    Val             interface{}
    Resp            chan interface{}
}

func HandleFuncExmpl(c echo.Context) error {
    cmdChan := c.Get("cmdChan").(chan CmdOp)
}
```

Comment: Hi, I would use context only to pass some additional information like request ID or metadata. For passing essential dependencies to the handler pass them directly via arguments (extend method). By being explicit about what the handler needs by giving it proper type and number of arguments you get more readable, understandable and safe code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll use the extend method for sending commands via channel